# Keeping polygon perpendicular to camera

Tags: opengl, glsl, webgl

Currently I'm using WebGL for a school project, and am stuck on trying to keep an object perpendicular to the camera while allowing rotation of the rest of the scene.

I currently have a cube and other object on the canvas, and they're being successfully rotated using a quaternion and converting that to a rotation matrix. I would now like to add a simple square within the scene, but have it consistently perpendicular to the camera.

In thinking about this, I've considered an approach using multiple vertex shader programs for the different objects in the scene: 1 for handling the positioning of all objects in the scene that can be rotated, and another vertex shader corresponding to the square that I don't want rotated.

Though, I really don't know if this approach will work as expected, as I am still a novice at WebGL.

Would there be a better approach to this? I greatly apologize if there's  a lack of info given, and can give any more info if needed. I've searched quite a bit for something involving this, but have hit a dead end.

Thank you!

Comment: This technique is called billboarding. It shouldn't be too hard to find a simple explanation in GLSL, I found one [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Unity/Billboards). That uses the deprecated `gl_ModelViewMatrix`, etc. but you get the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more step by step tutorial: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/billboards-particles/billboards/.